# How to Use OpenFileDialog to copy a file with datetime stamped filename from souce Dir to target Dir IN VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

C:\Restore\databasefile.accdb

D:\Backup\xyz.accdb

I wish to copy **xyz.accdb** from **"D:\Backup"** to **"C:\Restore"** (the xyz.accdb should be renamed to **'databasefile'.accdb** when copied to "C:\Restore").

the filename **'xyz'.accdb** is a datetime stamped which is not unique at some point . example is **04-04-2021.accdb**, **04-05-2021.accdb** and so on.

My question is, how can use  **OpenFileDialog** to copy a non-unique filename from **D:\Backup\xyz.accd** to **C:\Restore\databasefile.accdb** (filename renamed to 'databasefile'.accdb)

**i am using VB.NET - Visual studio 2019**
I will highly appreciate if someone can help me out with  a code or directives how to archive this. Thanks

Comment: Hint: if you name the files with a yyyy-MM-dd format, they will appear in date order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to copy a file selected by the user through an OpenFileDialog, you can do it like this:

```
Dim open As New OpenFileDialog()
open.Title = "Select the file you wish to copy"
If open.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    IO.File.Copy(open.FileName, "C:\Restore\databasefile.accdb", True)
End If
```